# How do i get all answers that lead to a specific output

Tags: prolog

So i am starting with Prolog and had an example task, where i have some points that form a maze and i want to know all the nodes that can lead to node 1.

```
connected(1,2).
connected(3,4).
connected(5,6).
connected(7,8).
connected(9,10).
connected(12,13).
connected(13,14).
connected(15,16).
connected(17,18).
connected(19,20).
connected(4,1).
connected(6,3).
connected(4,7).
connected(6,11).
connected(14,9).
connected(11,15).
connected(16,12).
connected(14,17). 
connected(16,19).

reachable(X,Z) :- connected(X,Z).
reachable(X,Z) :- connected(X,Y),reachable(Y,Z).
```

I used the following query:
    `reachable(X,1).`
which resulted in a simple false and not all nodes that lead to 1.
I on the other hand expected something like this:

```
x = 4;
```

It should be noted that this is a directed Graph.

Comment: Please state the problem more carefully. Currently it is unclear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: is the graph directed, or should it be undirected? For a directed graph, your predicate works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I execute the query `reachable(X,1).`, I get the expected result:

```
?- reachable(N,1).
N = 4 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 5 ;
N = 6 ;
false.
```

Which is what one expects based on the following graph:

[image: graph showing the connections]

generated with: `dot -Tpng < conn.dot > conn.png` and `conn.dot`:

```
digraph G {
    1 -> 2;
    3 -> 4;
    5 -> 6;
    7 -> 8;
    9 -> 10;
    12 -> 13;
    13 -> 14;
    15 -> 16;
    17 -> 18;
    19 -> 20;
    4 -> 1;
    6 -> 3;
    4 -> 7;
    6 -> 11;
    14 -> 9;
    11 -> 15;
    16 -> 12;
    14 -> 17;
    16 -> 19;
}
```

Please check whether you have made a small typo or space error in your Prolog file.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a typo.